# NSArray acts weirdly with objects going out of scope

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsarray

I have a weird problems with `NSArray` where some of the members of the objects in my array are going out of scope but not the others:

I have a simple object called Section.
It has 3 members.

```
@interface Section : NSObject {
    NSNumber *section_Id;   
    NSNumber *routeId;
    NSString *startLocationName;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)  NSNumber *section_Id;  
@property(nonatomic,retain)  NSNumber *routeId;
@property(nonatomic,retain)  NSString *startLocationName;
@end


@implementation Section

@synthesize section_Id; 
@synthesize routeId;
@synthesize startLocationName;

//Some static finder methods to get list of Sections from the db
+ (NSMutableArray *) findAllSections:{


- (void)dealloc {
    [section_Id release];
    [routeId release];
    [startLocationName release];

    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I fill it from a database in a method called `findAllSection`

```
self.sections = [Section findAllSections];
```

In find all sections I create some local variables fill them with data from db.

```
NSNumber *secId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:id_section];
NSNumber *rteId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:id_route];
NSString *startName = @"";
```

Then create a new Section and store these local variable's data in the Section

```
Section *section = [[Section alloc] init];

section.section_Id = secId;
section.routeId = rteId;
section.startLocationName = startName;
```

Then I add the section to the array

```
[sectionsArray addObject:section];
```

Then I clean up, releasing local variables and the section I added to the array
    [secId release];
    [rteId release];
    [startName release];
    [locEnd_name release];

```
[section release];
```

In a loop repeat for all Sections (release local variables and section is done in every loop)

The method returns and I check the array and all the Sections are there. I cant seem to dig further down to see the values of the Section objects in the array (is this possible)

Later I try and retrieve one of the Sections

I get it from the array

```
Section  * section = [self.sections objectAtIndex:row];
```

Then check the value

```
NSLog(@" SECTION SELECTED:%@",section.section_Id);
```

But the call to `section.section_Id` crashed as `section.section_Id` is out of scope.

I check the other members of this Section object and they're ok.
After some trial and error I find that by commenting out the release of the member variable the object is OK.

```
//[secId release];
[rteId release];
[startName release];
[locEnd_name release];


[section release];
```

My questions are:

Am I cleaning up okay?

Should I release the object added to an array and the local variable in the function?

Is my dealloc okay in Section?

Does this code look ok and should I be looking elsewhere for the problem?

I'm not doing anything complicated just filling array from DB use it in Table Cell.

I can comment out the release but would prefer to know why this works, and if I shouldn't be doing this. The only place that `secId` is released is in the dealloc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll second (third) the suggestion to read the memory management rules.

The TL;DR version is anything you `alloc` and call a method with `init` in the method name on is your responsibility to release. For instance:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", someObject];
```

In this case you must release `string`. However:

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", someObject];
```

Here `string` is autoreleased. It's basically equivalent to this:

```
NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat@"%@", someObject] autorelease];
```

...meaning that the next time through the event loop (which means possibly as soon as your function returns), the system will send a `release` message to it for you. Apple calls these "convenience methods".

If you have something like this:

```
NSString *string = @"foo";
```

Then `string` is pointing to an instance of NSString that is created by the runtime when your program initializes and won't go out of scope until your program terminates. Never `release` these either.

Again, read the guidelines and bookmark them. But this should answer your direct question.

Comment: Cheers all.
//TODO: Friday - R.T.F.M. (Read the Feckin Manual)
or should that be R.T.F.MMM (Read the Feckin Mem. Mgt. Manual)   ;)

Answer (score 4):

You should not be releasing `secId`, `rteId`, or `startName`. `secId` and `rteId` are pointers to `NSNumber` instances created with a factory method that returns an already-autoreleased object. Static strings (i.e. `@""`) do not need to be released. You need to re-read the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html). Then read it again ;-) It will be your friend.

Comment: @Barry beat me too it. He's right, though. With few exceptions, you only release objects created from `init`, `copy` or `new` methods.

Comment: I would recommend taking anything anyone on SO tells you about memory management very lightly. Go by the memory management rules Barry linked. People have a tendency to restate them informally and often say it slightly wrong. For example, kubi just omitted `copy` and `mutableCopy`. So don't lean too much on restatements of the rules.

Comment: Barry's right, but just to clarify, you shouldn't be releasing the **local** `NSNumber` instances you're creating. You should still release the instance variables. Generally, you can do this more stylishly by assigning nil to the property (`self.section_Id = nil;`) instead of calling `release` on the instance variable.

Comment: @warrenm, please do *not* assign `nil` to a property to release the instance variable in your desctructor. Doing so is a recepie for pain if you ever add side-effects to your property setter. The standard practice is to use raw instance variables in the `init` and `dealloc` methods and property access everywhere else.

Comment: I respectfully disagree, unless you're using KVO. In every other situation, and **especially** if you're adding custom behavior to a mutator, you should be double-checking how you perform the eventual release, in which case you can change as necessary. Otherwise, there's no reason to disparage that choice as a matter of style.

Comment: @warrenm Objective-C is not C++ where destructors get called automatically (and appropriately) for class hierarchies. That's why you have to explicitly call `[super dealloc]` in a subclass `-dealloc` method. In this case, it's impossible for the superclass to know whether a subclass (or a category) has changed the mutator's behavior. @bbum and other Apple developers routinely suggest using direct instance variable access in `-dealloc` (in fact, that's a main reason access to @synthesized instance variables was added in the latest runtime).

Comment: @warrenm Just to clarify, I am not recommending direct access instead of property access everywhere, just in `-init..` and `-dealloc`.

Comment: @Barry_Wark Understood. I think your explanation makes the case for calling `release` within `dealloc`.

Answer (score 3):

You're releasing objects you don't own. You should read the [memory management rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/).